# How do I implement a down pointer in a linked list but only on the first node of each line?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

**I'm writing code for a project where I'm reading in from a text file a string line by line and trying to put each character into a node. The first variable is the "head" node and I just need to connect the head node to the row below. Every single node doesn't need a down pointer just the first node for each row. Here's my code for reference. **
[image: Current Code]

I have no idea how to implement the down pointer so please help.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: *"I just need to connect the head node to the row below"* -- You're blinding yourself to possibilities. Reconsider this.

Comment: Split the responsibilities up so you have a linked list of linked lists of data. Gives you the 2D structure you want but without having to have nodes that are both a data entry AND a linked list.

Answer (score 2):

At least as I understand it, what you really want is two linked lists:

```cpp
struct line { 
    char data;
    line *next;
};

struct lines {
    line *current;
    lines *next;
};
```

That said, linked lists are only rarely useful, and a linked list of char is probably one of the most completely useless possibilities of all. I suppose there must be *some* situation in which it might provide some minimal utility, but I honestly find it hard to imagine what it could possibly be. Even when you invent tasks specifically intended to favor linked lists...they still usually lose.

[Bjarne Stroustrup video about how poorly linked lists work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo&t=10s)